# A laptop with OS "ubuntu"

Tags: laptop

I want to install the UBUNTU operating system on my "DELL XPS" laptop, but all installation packages are only for "DESKTOP".
Where can I download the **UBUNTU** installation package for "DELL XPS" **laptops**?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a desktop package on a laptop.

You just can't use it on a mobile device like a phone or tablet.

Note: another answer did mention server setups. I think that's probably not relevant to your question, but if you're curious, a desktop install isn't ideal for setting up a server. If you were setting up a server, you'd have a much better experience if you just went ahead and installed a server package. But in the case of the server vs. desktop version, it's really a question of the software that is installed by default, rather than the operating system build itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't ask about phone or tablet. 
I was asking about laptop "DELL XPS"

Comment: Then you can stop at the first line. A desktop package is suitable for a laptop.

Answer (score 2):

The "desktop" installers are called so not because they are intended for desktop computers (you may use it either on a desktop or laptop, no problem), but because they include by default a **graphical desktop**, which is a primary method of interacting with the system for a personal computer user.

Besides the desktop installers, you have **server** installers, intended for servers, that are usually operated remotely from command line and don't run any kind of graphical desktop.

That's the main difference between these two kinds of installers. So the desktop installer is the appropriate one for use on a laptop.

Answer (score 2):

The DESKTOP refers to what is shown on the screen; ie. it's a desktop or GUI interface, with window manager & all running underneath desktop.

Your alternative is a text based SERVER system, which has no display manager, no window manager and thus no desktop on it. The desktop refers to the software layer (GUI or *graphical user interface*).

As for which desktop you wish to install, that is up to you.

Ubuntu Desktop by default includes the GNOME Desktop; but you can also use Xfce Desktop as found on Xubuntu, LXQt Desktop on used by Lubuntu, MATE Desktop as used by Ubuntu-MATE, KDE Plasma Desktop as used by Kubuntu, Budgie Desktop etc...  as you have many choices available via

https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

If you count, Ubuntu offers ten (10) Desktop *flavors* too, plus the default GNOME used by Ubuntu Desktop.

Desktop refers to the software on it, not your hardware. It can be installed on laptops as well as desktops machines, as the desktop refers to software, not the form factor of your chosen hardware.

Comment: There may be little new with this answer; mostly the choice of Desktops which to me at least, matters.   When I turn this system on (*desktop form factor, my favorite*) I can select which desktop I'll use in a session as I prefer multi-desktop environments. If I grabbed & used a laptop of mine instead, I'd have the same choice of desktops too, with me selecting the session/desktop I'll use when I login it (*excluding machines used in QA which are usually single desktop only*)